# 220v to 5v AC to DC Rectifier IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, power-electronics

I am working on a small project where I need to convert 220v AC to 5v DC with at least 100mA current. I am currently using Hi-Link's converter to achieve the goal and it's working great.

I am looking to use something that's much smaller than this. I found that there are some rectification ICs like MB10F which are able to achieve a similar goal and are substantially smaller. However, their voltage/current output don't seem to match mine.

I wanted to know if anyone is aware of an IC that matches this requirement. It would be great if you could point me in the right direction, or to websites where I can run queries such as these. I tried Mouser but I couldn't use their interface to achieve my goal. How do you generally find ICs like these?

Comment: To the close-voters: "How do you generally find ICs like these?" clearly does not ask for a specific product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a device is impractical to design as an dedicated IC because of the high voltages involved and the need for isolation. You've found a simple bridge rectifier which is just a small part of what you need.

In this case you need a power supply *module*. These are available in PCB-mountable packages similar to ICs but generally larger. I found a whole category of these at [Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/power-supplies-board-mount/ac-dc-converters/923) for example.

You also need to know how to work with potentially<sup>1</sup> lethal voltages on the same PCB as low voltages. I'm not sure it's a good idea to design something like this on a PCB if you're not sure what a bridge rectifier does. At least you need to maintain a good isolation distance between low and high voltages.

<sup>1. Pun</sup>

Comment: Strictly speaking, a module *is* an integrated circuit.